# How can I grab 2 things from 2 different def functions and use them in a different def

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to grab both the image and audio from those and use them both in another def, how would I do that?

```
def image():
    image = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Image Files",".png .jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
```

```
def audio():
    audio = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Audio Files",".mp3 .wav"),("all files","*.*")))
```

This is the def I'm trying to use them in.

```
def create():
    os.system(f"ffmpeg -i {image} -i {audio} -vf scale=1920:1080 output.mp4")
```

Comment: As an aside, probably prefer `subprocess.run` over `os.system`; `subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', image(), '-i', audio(), '-vf', 'scale=1920:1080', 'output.mp4'])`

Answer (score 2):

You need to *return* the value of `image` and `audio`, like so:

```
def image():
    image = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Image Files",".png .jpg"),("all files","*.*")))

    return image

def audio():
    audio = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Audio Files",".mp3 .wav"),("all files","*.*")))

    return audio
```

And then use them:

```
def create():
    image = image()
    audio = audio()
    
    os.system(f"ffmpeg -i {image} -i {audio} -vf scale=1920:1080 output.mp4")
```

Additionally, it'd probably be a good idea to wrap the file names in [`shlex.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) to make it work with file names that have spaces in them and files named by a malicious user.

Answer (score 0):

Just return values from the other functions and call them in the function which needs these values.

```
def image():
    image = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Image Files",".png .jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
    return image

def audio():
    audio = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Audio Files",".mp3 .wav"),("all files","*.*")))
    return audio

def create():
    os.system(f"ffmpeg -i {image()} -i {audio()} -vf scale=1920:1080 output.mp4")
```

What actually happens when you return a value:

Ex 1.

```
def example():
    a = "Hello"
    return a
value = example() # --> value = a = "Hello"
```